# Do Safari's dev tools and profiler timelines affect the performance of a web page?

Tags: ios, memory, webkit, mobile-safari, safari-web-inspector

I have an iOS device that crashes with an "exceeded mem limit" error in the system logs when visiting a particular web page. To help debug, I have connected the device to the Safari dev tools on my laptop.

Does the act of using the dev tools to observe the console log and the profiler timelines impact the memory used—or the memory available—on the iOS device, putting a "thumb on the scale", as it were?

I've been told that this is true for chrome dev tools, and that I should make sure to e.g. clear the console log between reloads when debugging memory issues.

I want to be sure that the tools and techniques I use to diagnose memory leaks are not skewing the results.

Answer (score 1):

According to WebKit's web inspector reference for the [Timelines Tab](https://webkit.org/web-inspector/timelines-tab/), only the Media & Animations , Memory and JavaScript Allocations timeline options are disabled by default because "...it can impact the performance of the inspected page during a timeline recording."

However, there is bound to be some overhead when using any profiling or Application Performance Management (APM) tools. In my experience, this is a main reason why we only include New Relic APM on a fixed number of clusters in production servers vs all.

Here's also a [reference to how profiling typically works](https://www.atatus.com/blog/what-is-code-profiling-a-detailed-explanation/#How-does-Profiling-Works?).